# How to execute the given "js files" on the Fabric network?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm studying Hyperledger Fabric with the documentation(https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.0/write_first_app.html)

I'm done with two samples, which is "Building Your First network" & "Writing Your First Application"

I'm also done adding 1 extra peer to each organization, by modifying certain files, as well as done trying all commands on "Writing Your Fist Application" session.

Now, I'd like to execute the same commands(e.g. Querying all cars, Adding new cars or whatever) on the first network where I have built up, not on the test Fabcar network.

The thing is that I really have no idea what to do and how to do, even though I know how to handle NodeJS program(by Writing Application webpage)

So I'd like to ask you some questions.

1. Should I modify some files in order to "move" all necessary things to my network? if so, which file should I modify?
2. By any chance, Could you please tell me the correct steps to make it? I feel like I need to install and instantiate the required smart contract on my peers. Am I right?

I really appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you would need to read some documentation online that will help you understand the architecture and how you can build up the packages as hyperledger fabric provided freedom to users to create use case specific configurations.

To start with.

1. Make sure you have have understood the concept of peer, orderer, couchdb, ca authority. Those 4 things you need to play with most of the times.
2. Assuming you have installed **nodejs** and able to run node through terminal,  Read through the following example 
   [Tuna Fish example](https://github.com/hyperledger/education), it help you to understand the concept of injecting, updating, querying blockchin ledger. Also, It will help understand the usage of **Nodejs backend** and **angularjs basic UI**.  or use the other examples as you have seen on the fabric-samples github repository. [Fabric Samples](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples). **[Balance Transfer](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.1/balance-transfer)** will help you understand the channel and chaincode operations using Node JS. **[Build your first network](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/tree/release-1.1/first-network)** will help you understand the configuration files(concentrate on docker-compose.yaml, scipt.js and byfn.js)

Then to answer your questions.

1. you just have to modify the mount drive config variables in docker-componse-cli.yaml. Then you can edit your startup script based on how you want to move chaincode to your peer.
2. you need to install chaincode on all the peers that are part of that channel. And you only need to instantiate chaincode once per channel.

Installation and instantiation combination is a powerful feature because it allows for a peer to interact with the same chaincode container across multiple channels. The only prerequisite is for the actual chaincode source files to be installed on the peer's file system. As such, if a piece of common chaincode is being used across dozens of channels, a peer would need only a single chaincode container to perform read/writes on all the channel ledgers.

To run the node js files on the fabric network. 
welcome to blockchain world :)